# Application of classical Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

I was asked a question I don't know how to answer, because I too do not know classical Galois theory, so I'm hoping someone may illuminate the process by which we derive an answer.

Consider polynomial expressions of the form $-ax^n + x - b = 0,$ for $-a$ and $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}.$ Then, for what values of $n$ is this polynomial solvable in terms of radicals?

I suspect the answer is for $n \leq 4$ but I don't know how to go about proving this, how do we know there doesn't exist some extremely large integer which admits a solvable Galois group?

Comment: I still don't know this stuff,  but it has to do with the fact that $S_n,\,n\gt4$ is not solvable (I think).

Comment: General quintics and above are not solvable in the general case, but I'm wondering if polynomials of this specific form are solvable, for there exists many "solvable" higher degree polynomials. For instance, $0 = x^5 - 1$ is solvable.

Comment: Right,  I was just going to add that.  Not sure if this is one of the exceptions.

Comment: For Galois theory to give interesting answers, we need to edit the question a bit. You see, if we view the polynomial defining an extension of $\Bbb{R}$ we know right away that the splitting field if either $\Bbb{R}$ of $\Bbb{C}$, both obviously solvable extensions of $\Bbb{R}$. If we constrain $a$ and $b$ to rational numbers the answer is, by classical Galois theory, that for most (for a suitable definition of "most") pairs $(a,b)$ the polynomial is not solvable in terms of radicals (over $\Bbb{Q}$).

Comment: (cont'd) A more interesting question is the one in-between, when we look at the splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$. I think that the answer is still that "generically" we get an unsolvable Galois group. I'm fairly confident a general answer to that question is also known, but I cannot recite one nor give a link.

Comment: The case of quintics is of special interest, and a good summary by Eric Weisstein is [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html). In particular, the result of Spearman & Williams (over $\Bbb{Q}$) is interesting. I don't know if a similar result is available for the base field $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$.